How can I troubleshoot inconsistent Mono.fromFuture method calls?
I am working on a Spring Boot project running Webflux (version 5.3).
In REST endpoint, there are two async updates to two different AWS DynamoDB accounts, aggregated together with a Mono.when(). There is a Datadog metric reported before calling Mono.when (metric-1)  and a metric reported in the DynamoDB update method for success (metric-2) and failure (metric-3).
Mono<Void> result = Mono.empty();
        if (//valid check) {
            //Report Datadog metric-1
            result = Mono.when(updateDynamoDBTable(event, dynamoDbAsyncClient1),
                               updateDynamoDBTable(event, dynamoDbAsyncClient2));
        }
        return result;

//call the given client to update the given record
private updateDynamoDBTable(Event event, DynamoDbAsyncClient dynamoDbAsyncClient){
    return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(event))
                .map(this::toDynamoRequest)
                .flatMap(item -> Mono.fromFuture(dynamoDbAsyncClient.updateItem(toDynamoRequest)))
                .doOnNext(uir -> //Report Datadog metric 2)
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                      //Report Datadog metric 3
                        };
                    return Mono.empty();
                });
}  

When this application runs under high load in a production environment, I am seeing that the metrics count does not match. The number of times Mono.when is called is much higher than the DynamoDB success metric. There are no failures logged or reported by Datadog.
How can I debug this mismatch? Which Thread pool is used by the WebFlux project when a default thread pool is not defined?

I added a .doFinally method to track the signal type and report a metric for cancelled. I can now see that the missing calls are cancelled.
Here is the updated code:
    Mono<Void> result = Mono.empty();
            if (//valid check) {
                //Report Datadog metric-1
                result = Mono.when(updateDynamoDBTable(event, dynamoDbAsyncClient1),
                                   updateDynamoDBTable(event, dynamoDbAsyncClient2));
            }
            return result;
    
    //call the given client to update the given record
    private updateDynamoDBTable(Event event, DynamoDbAsyncClient dynamoDbAsyncClient){
        return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(event))
                    .map(this::toDynamoRequest)
                    .flatMap(item -> Mono.fromFuture(dynamoDbAsyncClient.updateItem(toDynamoRequest)))
                    .doOnNext(uir -> //Report Datadog metric 2)
                    .onErrorResume(e -> {
                          //Report Datadog metric 3
                            };
                        return Mono.empty();
                    })
                    .doFinally(signalType -> {
                          if (signalType == Cancel) {
                          //Report Datadog metric 4
                            };
                        return Mono.empty();
                    });
    }  

I can now see that the number of calls are now matching - Mono.when (metric-1)  = success (metric-2) + failure (metric-3) +  cancelled (metric-4).
I am still trying to find why the cancellations are happening.
